# Javascript constructors and new operator

Tags: javascript

Constructors are like normal functions in javascript.

```
function Vehicle (param1, param2){
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
}
```

Why do we need to call them with new operator

```
1) var car = new Vehicle ('abc' , 'def');
```

Why not like this and explicitly return 'this' ?

```
2) var car = Vehicle('abc' , 'def'); //Like a simple function call.
```

In 2) object is not created.
 and car.param1 gives undefined.

What is it that "new" is doing behind the scene?

Comment: 2) would probably work if you'd type `return this` at the end of the function. A constructor is a function that has no return type, because it creates an instance of the type it is a constructor for. When you use `new`, you tell the system that you're trying to call a constructor rather than a normal function.

Comment: Because this is how Javascript constructors works, otherwise you could use a **function** just like @Glubus suggested. [I think you should read the doc, before asking new questions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling function using new will convert your function from this

```
function Vehicle (param1, param2){
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
}
```

to this

```
function Vehicle (param1, param2){
  var this={};
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
  return this;
}
```

In 2) object will be created. and car.param1 wont come undefined . If you write function like this

```
function Vehicle (param1, param2){
      var obj={};
      this.param1 = param1;
      this.param2 = param2;
      return obj;
    }
```